# Recomendations on Windows 10 Universal App using users Calendar VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, calendar, windows-10-universal

I am looking for

> How to Integrate Calendar with a Windows 10 Universal App VB.NET.
>
> Some recommendations/tips on best practices.
>
> Comparisions on approach suggeted.

Recommendations on which is better, to open users Windows calendar integrated on my app, or add appointments to a database and sync it with users calendar on demand, for example.

VB.NET tutorials on using calendar would be greatly appreciated too...

Comment: Would be better if you ask this question in Stack Exchange > Programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CalendarView is a control itself in the Universal Windows Apps.

This View provides a visual calendar display to select a date. This view can be customized,  to change the language, start date, end date etc

**To add into xaml page, use following tag**

```
<CalendarView SelectionMode="Single" CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging" IsGroupLabelVisible="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsOutOfScopeEnabled="True" Language="en-US" CalendarIdentifier="GregorianCalendar"/>
```

Now its purely requirement driven, if you do not want to use framework provided control, you can write your own custom control. this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windowsapp/930/create-user-control-xaml-csharp) has good material on user control.

The [datepicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.aspx) class and [about](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726(v=vs.85).aspx) can also be reffered

Comment: Yes, Anil Kumar, this was my first idea, BUT I simply cannot find any documentation on how to integrate the CalendarVIEW with users account calendar. Tons of C# codes, but none complete and I wasnt able to make any of those work, thats why I started to think it could be the worst approach...